# Create shapefiles with GDAL and Android studio Warning error on shapefiles created in projection WGS_1984_UTM_Zone_18S

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, shapefile, ogr2ogr, ogr

This is my method that creates the shapefile, but the file gets a warning when opened in ArcMap:
The added layers have an extension that is not consistent with the associated spatial reference information

```java
private fun createShpFile(list : MutableList<ParcelasModel>) {
val file = File(DirectoryPath().getInternalStorageDirectoryPath(this)+"/APPGIS/Shapes/"+list[0].TIPO_FORMA )
        val driver  = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
        if(file.exists()){
            driver.DeleteDataSource(file.path)
        }
        val ds : DataSource = driver.CreateDataSource(file.absolutePath.toString())
        val spatialReference = SpatialReference()
        spatialReference.ImportFromProj4("+proj=utm +zone=18 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs")
        val vector = Vector<String>()
        vector.addElement("ENCODING=UTF-8")
        val layer = ds.CreateLayer(list[0].TIPO_FORMA+"_"+list[0].N_OPE+"_"+list[0].ID_TOPO ,spatialReference, ogr.wkbPolygon,vector)
        createField(layer)
        for(obj in list){
            val featureDef = layer.GetLayerDefn()
            val geo = ogr.CreateGeometryFromWkt(obj.WKT)
            geo.AssignSpatialReference(spatialReference)
            val outFeature =  converterVariable(featureDef,obj)
            outFeature.SetGeometry(geo)
            layer.CreateFeature(outFeature)
        }
        layer.SyncToDisk()
        DirectoryPath().scanFile(this,file.path+"/"+list[0].TIPO_FORMA+"_"+list[0].N_OPE+"_"+list[0].ID_TOPO)
    }
```

Comment: What is the extent of the dataset? My guess is that the coordinates values are in latitude-longitude or web Mercator rather than UTM 18 South.

Comment: That's how it is estimated, the error was the value of the coordinates, create a method to convert the decimal degrees to meters to create the polygons, thank you very much